# Reading txt file into Anaconda?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, jupyter

Trying to read a `.txt` file into my Jupyter notebook.

This is my code:

```
acm = pd.read_csv('outputacm.txt', header=None, error_bad_lines=False)
print(acm)
```

Here is a sample of my txt file:

```
2244018
#*OQL[C++]: Extending C++ with an Object Query Capability.
#@José A. Blakeley
#year1995
#confModern Database Systems
#citation14
#index0
#arnetid2

#*Transaction Management in Multidatabase Systems.
#@Yuri Breitbart,Hector Garcia-Molina,Abraham Silberschatz
#year1995
#confModern Database Systems
#citation22
#index1
#arnetid3

#*Overview of the ADDS System.
#@Yuri Breitbart,Tom C. Reyes
#year1995
#confModern Database Systems
#citation-1
#index2
#arnetid4
```

And the different symbols are supposed to correspond to:

```
#* --- paperTitle
#@ --- Authors
#year ---- Year
#conf --- publication venue
#citation --- citation number (both -1 and 0 means none)
#index ---- index id of this paper
#arnetid ---- pid in arnetminer database
#% ---- the id of references of this paper (there are multiple lines, with each indicating a reference)
#! --- Abstract
```

Not sure how to set this up so the data gets read correctly. Ideally, I would want a data frame where each category is a different column, and then all the entries in the document are rows. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My regex is not as up to speed as it should be, but the below might work so long as the data remains in the same form and the column names aren't duplicated in other lines:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

path = r"filepath.txt"

f = open(path, 'r')

year = []
confModern = []
#continue for all columns

for ele in f:
    if len(re.findall('year', ele)) > 0:
       year.append(ele[5:])
    if len(re.findall('confModern', ele)) > 0:
       year.append(ele[12:])
    # continue for all columns with the needed string

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'year' : year ...#continue for each list})
```